# When user hit enter, it changes dropdown menu content and textfield data to its default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a form where i need such facility where user input some data in textfield and hits enter that time using jquery it should create new controls like new textfield, dropdown menu, textfield. and its works also, but it has a bug like when user input another data and hits enter that time value of previous controls, dropdown and textfield changes to its default. help me to solve it

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addMbo(value){
var div = document.getElementById('mboTable');
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    event.preventDefault();
var divName = document.getElementById('mboName');
var divState = document.getElementById('mboState');
var divProgress = document.getElementById('mboProgress');

divName.innerHTML = divName.innerHTML + "<input class=form-control type=text     name=mboName value='" + value + "' id=mboNamw/>"
divState.innerHTML = divState.innerHTML + "<select class=form-control > <option value=1>In Progress </option><option <value=2>Completed</option><option  value=3>Cancled</option></select>"
divProgress.innerHTML = divProgress.innerHTML + "<input class=form-control type=text name=progress id=progress />"
document.getElementById('mboNameInput').value = null;


}
}

</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <b>Objectives</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <b>Status</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <b>Compl. %</b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="mboTable">
                <div id="mboName" class="col-sm-5"></div>
                <div id="mboState" class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div id="mboProgress" class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" id="mboNameInput"  class="form-control " onkeydown="addMbo(this.value)" placeholder="Your MBO...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t33rdra6/14/)

Comment: It is because you are dynamically creating a form and all elements have the same `ID`. you need to create a +1 to the id's to make them unique.

Comment: i have edited my question plz check, sorry for giving you wrong info about question. @AdamBuchananSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below solution will work out for you

```js
$(function() {

  $("#mboNameInput").on("keydown", function(e) {
    
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var $nameDiv= $("#mboName");
        var $stateDiv= $("#mboState");
        var $progressDiv= $("#mboProgress");
        
        $nameDiv.append($("<input/>").attr("type","text").attr("value",$(this).val()));
        $stateDiv.append($("<select/>").append($("<option/>").text("InProgress")).append($("<option/>").text("Completed")).append($("<option/>").text("Canceled")));
       $progressDiv.append($("<input/>").attr("type","text"));
        $(this).val('');
    }
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <tr>
    <th>Objectives</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>% Comp</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        
    <div id="mboTable">
    <td><div id="mboName" class="col-lg-4"></div></td>
    <td><div id="mboState" class="col-lg-5"></div></td>
    <td><div id="mboProgress" class="col-lg-3"></div></td>
  </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input type="text" id="mboNameInput"  class="form-control "  placeholder="Your MBO..."></div>
    </td></tr> </table>
```

Comment: its working fine just need to put one line 'e.preventDefault(); ' thanks .. :)